# Using view models, merged response in single page app or comply to the REST standard?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

For example, when you create a single page application using ASP.NET MVC and some Web API controllers using REST it tends to be a lot of request to the server because often the views depends on some complex data. In a normal web project I would definitely try to create as few request as possible and maybe this goes for single page apps to? In my case my app depends on two types of objects and some collections of the same types. On the client side I'm using Backbone.js and my controllers are handling one type each for `Get()`, `Get(int id)` like REST should be implemented. In my case this is not an open API, it's just my application who consumes it. This is an example of the JSON my app depends on.

```
{
    CurrentPage: {
        Heading: "Home",
        Id: "pages/193",
        Metadata: {
            Name: "Home",
            Title: null,
            Keywords: null,
            Description: null,
            DisplayInMenu: true,
            Published: "/Date(1334499539404)/",
            Changed: "/Date(1334499539404)/",
            ChangedBy: "Marcus",
            IsPublished: true,
            IsDeleted: false,
            Slug: null,
            Url: null,
            SortOrder: 0
        },
        Parent: {
            id: "pages/293",
            slug: "slug",
            url: "url"
        },
        Children: [
            "pages/226",
            "pages/257"
        ]
},
    ParentPage: {
        Heading: "Parent",
        Id: "pages/293",
        Metadata: {
            Name: "Parent",
            Title: null,
            Keywords: null,
            Description: null,
            DisplayInMenu: true,
            Published: "/Date(1334499539404)/",
            Changed: "/Date(1334499539404)/",
            ChangedBy: "Marcus",
            IsPublished: true,
            IsDeleted: false,
            Slug: "slug",
            Url: "url",
            SortOrder: 0
        },
        Parent: null,
        Children: []
},
    Children: [
        {
            Heading: "Foo",
            MainBody: null,
            Id: "pages/226",
            Metadata: {
                Name: "I'm an article",
                Title: null,
                Keywords: null,
                Description: null,
                DisplayInMenu: true,
                Published: "/Date(1334511318838)/",
                Changed: "/Date(1334511318838)/",
                ChangedBy: "Marcus",
                IsPublished: true,
                IsDeleted: false,
                Slug: "i-m-an-article",
                Url: "i-m-an-article",
                SortOrder: 1
            },
            Parent: {},
            Children: [ ]
        },
        {
            Heading: "Bar",
            MainBody: null,
            Id: "pages/257",
            Metadata: {
                Name: "Foo",
                Title: null,
                Keywords: null,
                Description: null,
                DisplayInMenu: true,
                Published: "/Date(1334953500167)/",
                Changed: "/Date(1334953500167)/",
                ChangedBy: "Marcus",
                IsPublished: true,
                IsDeleted: false,
                Slug: "foo",
                Url: "foo",
                SortOrder: 2
            },
            Parent: {},
            Children: [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When looking at the above response I'm convinced that the answer is to merge this data in my controller instead of fetching objects and collections by them self, but I'm still curious about a second opinion.

Comment: What you are doing with this merged response is just as RESTful if not more than exposing individual entities as resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with grabbing your collections separately from one another.
But if you're building a single-page app (or at least a page with highly-dynamic content), make sure to optimize your requests.

I'm seeing a lot of places where this could go wrong, but I'm also already seeing places where it's going right, instead.

You're already dealing with your articles as a collection.
You don't have your bodies in there, but again, that might be good or bad, depending on what you're looking to achieve.

I can tell you that downloading two-dozen 500-1500 word articles, plus comments for each, plus metadata/microdata for all of the above, in the same JSON response, is going to be just as miserable as downloading just the shells (for "latest-stories" widgets and document-tree views), and then grabbing the content for each in its own call...

But consider this: neither of those things is against the principles of REST.
REST just stipulates that you should transfer state, that every URL should point to a meaningful noun, and that the HTTP verbs you use should dictate what's done with that noun, and how to communicate the results of the doing back to the client.

REST isn't inherently hypermedia.  It's not necessarily about the rabbit-hole of having URL ties to every subset of data, where one item in a collection might have a url to an item of another collection, which might have a url to another collection, and you need to visit each of these to get all of the data you want, in order to display one media-rich blog post...

If you've got a hypermedia system working for you, congrats.
Seriously.  If you can pen that out on your own, good on you.
But REST just wants the URL to be unique, or, if a collection, wants the collection to come back in a predictable way, according to the URL.

So what's stopping you from coming up with a collection which happens to be an aggregate of other things?  REST couldn't care less about the parsing on the front end, OR the congregation on the back end.
Alternatively, if you stick with your current format, consider just-in-time data serving.

What I mean is this:
If I were to load all of my last 10 articles as a collection, and display them, I would hold off on fetching any comments at all, until the user clicked the "show more" button, or scrolled down far enough to see comments, et cetera, and then I would just collect the comments for that particular article.

The goal of the front-end isn't to try to limit all requests to 1 gigantic one.
The goal of the front-end is to load quickly, even if it's just to get to the point where you have a few widgets that say "loading..." and get out of the way, so that the user can interact with what IS there, ASAP, and to stream stuff in, invisible to the user (whether it's streamed on a timer, or streamed based on interaction with a button, or an event, or whatever).

This is all very doable with REST, and even doable with a hypermedia paradigm.
You just need to be careful with how much you ask for up front.